# WooCommerce Login "continue as guest" button gateway

Tags: wordpress, authentication, woocommerce, account

I have this string of code that changes the default WooCommerce checkout behavior in which when a person is in the cart and clicks "proceed to checkout" it redirects them to the WooCommerce "my account" login page. Then they login and redirect to the checkout page. My question is would there be a way to have this behavior but allow  people to bypass login by adding a button to the form that says "continue as guest". So the customer can click this button in on the login page and bypass the code that ensures the customer is logged in.

Thanks for the help!!!

```
add_action('template_redirect','check_if_logged_in');
    function check_if_logged_in()
    {
        $pageid = 48; // your checkout page id
        if(!is_user_logged_in() && is_page($pageid))
        {
            $url = add_query_arg(
                'redirect_to',
                get_permalink($pagid),
                site_url('/account/') // your my acount url
            );
            wp_redirect($url);
            exit;
        }
        if(is_user_logged_in())
        {
        if(is_page(50))//my-account page id
        {

            $redirect = $_GET['redirect_to'];
            if (isset($redirect)) {
            echo '<script>window.location.href = "'.$redirect.'";</script>';
            }

        }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is an option within woocommerce that may assist you? Log into the WordPress dashboard and navigate to WooCommerce → Settings → Checkout. You'll see a box with the label 'Enable guest checkout'. Tick this box and customers will be able to purchase without logging in or creating a user account.

Comment: thanks for the comment but I am aware of the guest checkout feature. This code essentially overrides that in a sense which forces any "non-logged in user" to go through the login screen. Basically this code forces the user to login before purchase but I need to overrider that with a guest button. Its the best checkout flow but woocoomerce doesn't not support this out of the box.